# Single failure result form ternary operator inside a list comprehension of a list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension, conditional-operator

Here is the problem I am looking at:  Take a list of dictionaries.  Inside this, you can have the obvious cases of valid and invalid results.  So you write a simple ternary operator inside a list comprehension to get out a default message on failure.  However, it gives the default for each failure.

In the case where you know all the lists are the same length, is it possible to reduce this down to a single failure message inside the same comprehension?

The goal in this example code is to make out have the value of 'DEFAULT' if the key is not in the dictionaries inside the list.  To test, a simple print is done:

```
print(out)
>>> ['DEFAILT']
```

Here is my test data and a simple, successful result:

```
lis_dic = [{1:'One',2:'Two',3:'Three'},
    {1:'Ichi',2:'Ni',3:'San'},
    {1:'Eins',2:'Zvi',3:'Dri'}]
key = 1
out = [i[key] for i in lis_dic]
print(out)
>>> ['One', 'Ichi', 'Eins']
```

Error handling attempts:

```
key = 4
out = [i[key] for i in lis_dic if key in i]
print(out)
>>> []

out = [i.get(key, 'DEFAILT') for i in lis_dic]
print(out)
>>> ['DEFAILT', 'DEFAILT', 'DEFAILT']

out = [i[key] if key in i else 'DEFAULT' for i in lis_dic ]
print(out)
>>> ['DEFAILT', 'DEFAILT', 'DEFAILT']
```

As you can see, all of those result in no result or three results, not a singular result.

I also tried moving the location of the else, but I kept getting syntax errors.

Oh, and this is not useful because it can change order of valid results:

```
out = list(set([i[key] if key in i else 'DEFAULT' for i in lis_dic ]))
```

Comment: You don't want `i[key] if key in i else 'DEFAULT'`.You want `i.get(key, 'DEFAULT')`

Comment: @hughdbrown You will note I tried i.get(key, 'DEFAULT') and got a result different from what I am looking for.

Comment: @e.mccormick You can accept an answer if you think they fit your needs...

Comment: Close to what you wrote: `list(filter(None, (i.get(key) for i in lis_dic))) or ['DEFAULT']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is not in any of the three dictionaries, so the `'DEFAULT'` value is generated three times. If the first dictionary held the value and the other two did not, you would get a list with one value and two `'DEFAULT'`s. Anyway, try:

```
out = [i[key] for i in lis_dic if key in i] or ['DEFAULT']
```

Comment: Nice.  I like how simple this is.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a constraint on your data structure, the simplest solution would be to transform it once so it is trivial to retrieve the information you need every time. This is also likely more efficient, depending on what you are actually doing.

The transformed data structure would look like this:

```
transformed_lis_dic = {
    1: ['One', 'Ichi', 'Eins'], 
    2: ['Two', 'Ni', 'Zvi'],
    3: ['Three', 'San', 'Dri']
}

out = transformed_lis_dic.get(key, ['DEFAULT'])
```

You could do the transformation this way:

```
from collections import defaultdict

transformed_lis_dic = defaultdict(list)
for dic in lis_dic:
    for key, val in dic.iteritems():
        transformed_lis_dic[key].append(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own function and either completely get all the keys, or just return a single default - eg:

```
lis_dic = [{1:'One',2:'Two',3:'Three'},
    {1:'Ichi',2:'Ni',3:'San'},
    {1:'Eins',2:'Zvi',3:'Dri'}]

from operator import itemgetter
def single(key, *dicts, **kwargs):
    default = kwargs.get('default', 'DEFAULT')
    try:
        return map(itemgetter(key), dicts)
    except KeyError:
        return default

print single(3, *lis_dic)
# ['Three', 'San', 'Dri']
print single(4, *lis_dic)
# DEFAULT
```